# How does predict deal with models that include the AsIs function?

Tags: r, modeling, predict

I have the model `lm(y~x+I(log(x))` and I would like to use `predict` to get predictions of a new data frame containing new values of `x`, based on my model. How does predict deal with the AsIs function `I` in the model? Does the `I(log(x))` need to be extra specified in the `newdata` argument of `predict` or does `predict` understand that it should construct and use `I(log(x))` from `x`?

**UPDATE**

@DWin: The way the variables enter in the model affect the coefficients especially for interactions. My example is simplistic but try this out

```
x<-rep(seq(0,100,by=1),10)
y<-15+2*rnorm(1010,10,4)*x+2*rnorm(1010,10,4)*x^(1/2)+rnorm(1010,20,100)
z<-x^2

plot(x,y)
lm1<-lm(y~x*I(x^2))
lm2<-lm(y~x*x^2)
lm3<-lm(y~x*z)


summary(lm1)
summary(lm2)
summary(lm3)
```

You see that lm1=lm3, but lm2 is something different (only 1 coefficient). Assuming you don't want to create the dummy variable `z` (computationally inefficient for large datasets), the only way to build an interaction model like lm3 is with `I`. Again this is a very simplistic example (that may make no statistical sense) however it makes sense in complicated models.

@Ben Bolker: I would like to avoid guessing and try to ask for an authoritative answer (I can't direct check this with my models since they are much more complicated than the example). My guess is that `predict` correctly assumes and constructs the `I(log(x))`

Comment: It can be tricky to get the data.frame names to be correct when you use 'predict'. Please construct a small example.

Comment: Why don't you try it out on a small example and see if it works as expected??  (That's what I would have to do.  My guess is that all the variables on the RHS of your formula, whether protected by `I()` or not, need to be specified in `newdata`.)

Comment: Furthermore, I'm not sure you even need to use `I()` with 'log'.

Comment: Please see my updated question with answers to your comments

Comment: The issue is that I suspect there isn't an authoritative answer other than the source code, careful reading of the documentation [I don't think it'll be stated anywhere explicitly but *might* be inferrable by putting together, e.g., `?predict` and `?I`], and experimentation.  If you get lucky you will get a "personal communication" (as in "I do this a lot and it seems to work"). I think it would (have) improve(d) the question quality to say "here's an example, it seems to work, but can anyone say if this is reliable in general?"

Comment: @BenBolker I did search the documentation but found nothing. Also searched the net. I guess that an answer from you guys with the 20k+ reputation in R, that's authoritative enough for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to make your variable names look like the term `I(x)`. Just use "x" in the newdata argument.

The reason `lm(y~x*I(x^2))` and `lm(y~x*x^2)` are different is that "^" and "*" are reserved symbols for formula in R. That's not the case with the `log` function. It is also incorrect that interactions can only be constructed with `I()`. If you wanted a second degree polynomial in R you should use `poly(x, 2)`. If you build with I(log(x)) or with just `log(x)` you should get the same model.  Both of them will get transformed to the predictor value properly with `predict` if you use:

```
newdata=dataframe( x=seq( min(x), max(x), length=10) )
```

Using `poly` will protect you from incorrect inferences that are so commonly caused by the use of `I(x^2)`.

Comment: Still `I` seems to me to be a lot more flexible in complex models? How else can one specify a model "on the fly" for example y~x+z+I(log(x)*z^2) and obtain the respective coefficients without resulting to dummy variables?

Comment: Why would you expect `log(x)` to only interact with `I(z^2)` and not the linear term? It's really the same issue as arises when people want to construct interaction terms with no main effects. Generally such efforts stem from misguided notions of statistical model construction. Constructing nonsensical models _should_ be difficult. This would make more sense: `y~ log(x)*poly(z, 2)`.

Comment: Although I agree with you in the statistical model construction part and I understand what you mean, my questions specifically asks how `predict` deals with `I` and has nothing to do with considerations on statistical model construction and selection. The models presented are examples to make my case.

Comment: I thought that part had been answered but I guess I got sidetracked. You do not need to make your variable names look like the term `I(x)`. Just use "x" in the newdata argument.

Comment: Thank you. Please edit your answer accordingly so that I can mark it as answered.